# Update table with calculated values from view based on same table on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table

tblCurrent:

```
  Ref  |   . .... .  . . |  Total A   |   Total B
 A001  |                 |    NULL    |     NULL
 A002  |                 |    NULL    |     NULL
 A003  |                 |    NULL    |     NULL
 A004  |                 |    NULL    |     NULL
```

I've created a view `vwCurrentB` that provides a count of records that meet specific criteria in the same table.

How can I updated fields `Total A` and `Total B` with relevant values from the view.  Both the table and view will have exactly the same number of records, with Ref being a unique key.  I just need to get the additional two columns in the view, into their respective records in the table?

Comment: It would be better to *not* store these calculated totals. As soon as you store such a calculation, you're immediately at risk of being out of date. Why do you not just use the view? If it's a performance concern, have you considered an indexed view?

Comment: Each day a 'snapshot' of the main system database (that powers a massive web application) is created, this snapshot is uploaded to our team's database.  Nothing will change in our database as it is only ever meant to be a daily (and historical) snapshot.  So in this instance, the solution is fine.

Comment: @aSystemOverload the day you move your system to a different server, you get new references or you want to implement the solution for different situations, you will be happy that the business intelligence does not rely on having data already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update tc
set TotalA = v.TotalA
   ,TotalB = v.TotalB
from tblCurrent tc
join vwCurrentB v on tc.Ref = v.Ref
```